# Call to a member function format() on string Error

Tags: php, symfony, datetime

I have a Date field:

```
 /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="date", type="date", nullable=false)
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="Vous devez entrer une date d'ouverture d'établissement")
     */
    private $date;
/**
     * Set date
     *
     * @param \DateTime $date
     *
     * @return Demandes
     */
    public function setDate($date)
    {
        $this->date =$date;
        return $this;
    }

/**
 * Get date
 *
 * @return \DateTime
 */
public function getDate()
{
    return $this->date;
}
```

Form :

```
$builder->add('titre')->add('descriptionEvenement')->add('date',DateType::class ,[
            'label' => 'My Date',
            'required' => false,
            'widget' => 'single_text',
            'format' => 'dd/MM/yyyy'
        ]) ->add('lieu')->add('eMail')->add('descriptionOrganisateur')
            ->add('save',SubmitType::class);

        $builder->get('date')->addModelTransformer(new CallbackTransformer(
            function ($value) {
                if(!$value) {
                    return new \DateTime('now +1 month');
                }
                return $value;
            },
            function ($value) {
                return $value;
            }
        ));
```

I am getting the following error:

> Call to a member function format() on string
>
> in vendor\doctrine\dbal\lib\Doctrine\DBAL\Types\DateTimeType.php (line
>   53)

```
public function convertToDatabaseValue($value, AbstractPlatform $platform)    {        return ($value !== null)            ? $value->format($platform->getDateTimeFormatString()) : null;    }
```

Any help please !

Comment: `getDate` is returning a string, not a `DateTime` object. Dump it to confirm.

Comment: You should typehint `setDate(\DateTimeInterface $date)`, so php will fail earlier if your entity is setted with invalid date (like string). Could you dump your entity just before the `flush`